# Why my pandas DataFrame didn't sort columns?

Tags: pandas

I'm following the book "*Python for Data Analysis: Data Wrangling with Pandas, NumPy, and IPython 2nd Edition, by Wes McKinne*" and the book said, pandas DataFrame automaticaly sort columns by its name.

[image: book example]

But what I tried didn't sort columns. it order just what I order.

why? The book was wrong?

[image: perfectly same code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries used to be unordered, [since python3.7, the order of keys in a dictionary is guaranteed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

python2.7:

```
>>> {'b': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 0}
```

python3.7:

```
>>> {'b': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}
{'b': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}
```

So, the book is wrong for recent python (I guess it was written a while ago). Anyway, before that, the order was not to be relied on, so this could have worked by implementation but was not reliable.

Comment: @jezrael no clue, I flagged a post to moderators once but got no feedback, I think I've had dozen of those… (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=24) for example)